# How to generate attributes dynamically in pydantic?

Tags: python, oop, attributes, pydantic

Let's say we have this list of names:

```
students = ['A','B','C']
```

and I have this model with pydantic:

```
class Student(BaseModel):
    name: str
    rank: int = 0
```

and I have this model that I want to fill the students in it dynamically and have like a template:

```
class MathClass(BaseModel):
    def __init__(self, student_names):
        self.students = []
        for student_name in student_names:
             self.students.append(Student(name=student_name))
```

When I launch my code with

```
math_class=MathClass(students)
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: "MathClass" object has no field "students"
```

Why is that happening? is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue has to do with not defining students in the model itself as well as not calling `__init__()` on the inherited class. I was able to get your code to run by modifying `MathClass` like so:

```
class MathClass(BaseModel):
   students: list = []
    
   def __init__(self, student_names: list):
        super().__init__()

        for student_name in student_names:
            self.students.append(Student(name=student_name))
```

Best of luck and happy coding!

Comment: it worked ! thank you :)
why should I call __init__ on the inherited class however?

Comment: Great question! We need to call the constructor of the inherited class explicitly even though you inherit from `BaseModel`  similar to other OOPLs. I'm not too familiar with pydantic so I am not exactly sure what it does under the hood.